Value null at 'roleArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null Service: AWSSecurityTokenService
I have the following Java code which I use to create to aws s3 bucket:
AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(awsArn);
    AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new AWSCredentials......)).build();
    AssumeRoleResult assumeResult = stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRequest);

During boot time I get error:
2024-05-24T17:32:15.874Z ERROR 13528 --- [platform] [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'roleArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 1b112442-8c58-14bc-a741-caf9062c9441; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1879) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1418) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1387) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.doInvoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1727) ~[aws-java-sdk-sts-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1694) ~[aws-java-sdk-sts-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1683) ~[aws-java-sdk-sts-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.executeAssumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:532) ~[aws-java-sdk-sts-1.12.322.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:501) ~[aws-java-sdk-sts-1.12.322.jar:na]

I created IAM account with API keys credentials and s3 bucket. But I can't find what configuration I need to make in order to fix this issue.

What is the value of awsArn?

Currently it's missing. I don't know where to get it from AWS and set it here.

You state:

I created IAM account with API keys credentials and s3 bucket. But I can't find what configuration I need to make in order to fix this issue.

You have created an IAM user and static credentials, but you actually need a role. In your code, you are attempting to use a role:
AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(awsArn);

You need a valid value for awsArn. The value should be the ARN of an IAM role that has the correct permissions to create an S3 bucket (and whatever other operations you need).
You should read the docs, or perhaps this article which explains AssumeRole.
